# Doesn't match table_names jdbc program showing result and sql showing result

Tags: oracle, jdbc

My jdbc program code

```
package table;
import java.sql.*;

public class sdfjksjk {

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.12:1521:aftdb";

   static final String USER = "system";
   static final String PASS = "manager";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{

      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);


      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData(); 
      ResultSet rs = md.
                getTables(null, "SYSTEM", "%", null);
      while (rs.next())
      { 
          System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
          } 

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
}
```

this code showing `231` table name,but in my sql developer `select table_name from user_tables` it showing `207` table names. What is the wrong in my program?

Comment: Show your extra table name

Comment: Why are you using the `SYSTEM` account? That should ***only*** be used for DBA work. Never, ever, under no circumstance use the `SYSTEM` (or `SYS`) account for "regular" development.

Comment: SYSTEM is my schema name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of `md.getTables` is a list of table types.

You supply the value `null` which lists all table types ("TABLE", "VIEW" and possibly other types).

In sql developer you are just seeing regular tables (not views).

**Edit:**

Make the call like this to just get regular tables:

```
String regularTables[] = new String[] {"TABLE"};

ResultSet rs = md.
                getTables(null, "SYSTEM", "%", regularTables);
```

Comment: then how to remove that views in jdbc program?

Comment: Specify that you only want "TABLE" objects. See edit in my answer.

Comment: `while (rs.next())
      { 
          System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
          } ` why all are that `3` number.can u explain why use that number

Comment: @user2854207 Because the third column is the table name, see [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) And he is using it, because your code is using it...